# How to generate a Google Docs with an embedded AppScript, using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm interested in generating a Google Document with a particular Apps Script from my library.
The way I have been creating the Documents has been through basically, Jeff Everhart's code as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbkY0OGhGdEFSbEZuX3BQR3ZQVVZZMEFYckxiUXxBQ3Jtc0tuWG0wWkF0UHVnbmhOelMzU0dZbFhWVkU4X2M4TXpIZVNHbFRYNXBWYWVFZEpQREFQZzE0R2djeDFTTWxZTTRtdGczWW80aXR5djhhTVd0TFpMQkthbEJLeUpkcW1FRmRLNDhtWVhOQ1VXT1hwNmM3VQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fjeffreyeverhart.com%2F2020%2F09%2F29%2Fauto-fill-a-google-doc-template-from-google-sheet-data%2F).

Is it possible that the code be changed as to have the new Google Docs have an embedded Apps Script right from the get go?

My reduced code:

```
  function createNewGoogleDocs() {
      const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('The template ID goes here');
      const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('The destination folder ID goes here');

      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  
    rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
      if (index === 0 ) return;
      if(row[rows[0].length - 1]) return;


      const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`First Column Name (${row[0]})`, destinationFolder);
      const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    
      // Hopefully here we can have the addition of the the Apps Script on the new Docs

      doc.saveAndClose();
      const url = doc.getUrl();
      sheet.getRange(index+1, rows[0].length).setValue(url);


    })

  }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `new Google Docs have an embedded Apps Script`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: make a copy of a google doc that has the script

Comment: Hello, @Tanaike. Thanks for commenting early. By "to have the new Google Docs have an embedded Apps Script", I mean that I want new Google Docs to have an Apps Script code already in place.

Down below, Cooper already answered, but I appreaciate you came to answer early.

Comment: @Cooper, yes! I already tried it out and works as I wanted. I really thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to create an Apps Script project bound to a Doc, you have to create it from that particular document. As it is said on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound):

> ***A script is bound to a Google Sheets, Docs, Slides, or Forms file if
> it was created from that document rather than as a standalone script.**
> The file that a bound script is attached to is called a "container."
> Bound scripts generally behave like standalone scripts except that
> they do not appear in Google Drive, they cannot be detached from the
> file they are bound to, and they gain a few special privileges over
> the parent file.*

If your end goal is to create a Doc with an embedded Apps Script from a different Apps Script project, you would have to first create that Doc/script as a template and then use [`makeCopy`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopy) to create a copy of the Doc/script.

I am documenting this answer to help other people on this community, please feel free to leave a comment in your need further assistance.